# Python multiprocessing getting stuck

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, redhat, pathos

I am running a multiprocessing code in python in linux redhat 7.9. However works fine in Windows.
Code getting stuck after few hours sometimes.

```
from pathos import pools, helpers
with pools._ProcessPool() as pool:
    all_forecast_result1 = pool.starmap(run_engine, all_forecast_params)
    pool.close()    
    pool.join()
```

Comment: #-> cat /proc/6085/stack
[<ffffffff97d12496>] futex_wait_queue_me+0xc6/0x130
[<ffffffff97d1323b>] futex_wait+0x17b/0x280
[<ffffffff97d14fa6>] do_futex+0x106/0x5a0
[<ffffffff97d154c0>] SyS_futex+0x80/0x190
[<ffffffff98393f92>] system_call_fastpath+0x25/0x2a
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff

Comment: Used pathos.helpers.freeze_support() as well but did not work

Comment: Post all relevant information **in the question**.

Comment: Can you provide code that can reproduce the problem? Similarly, if you have diagnostic information, could you provide that as well?  I also noticed that you are using `close` and `join` in a `with` context... which I believe is redundant, as leaving the `with` context should close the pool.

Comment: @AkashKhetan it might me a memory issue, I had a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75784038/python-multiprocessing-application-is-getting-stuck-in-docker-container